# Image is not getting displayed in Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, image

I am doing design work in asp.net and  I tried to design my web form by adding image to "Image Url".

Here is my code

```
<asp:Image ID="Image3" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/curta.png" />
```

I am sure this is the usual way of adding images to the web form. I have tried using this image in all the other web forms. It is getting displayed, but not getting displayed in this web form. Its really weird for me.!! I tried using many images but nothing is getting displayed in this web form alone and I have also tried adding the images in "Images" folder and directed the url to that position. Still it didn't work..!!

I don't know what is wrong. Sorry if the question seems to be a silly one.!!Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is your "curta.png" image? Is it in any of the root folder?

Answer (score 0):

May be you are doing some manipulations on the code behind page on that Image and it can cause your image to be not displayed.

If not, try to provide the absolute path of the image to ImageUrl attribute instead of the relative path.

Comment: How to provide absolute path to an image..? There is only one way of setting the path to an Image..!! @Shiran S Ekanayake

Comment: @Anusha in FileBrowser go to the location where you have stored the image. Then hold the shift key and right click on the image. Then you can find there is a option "Copy as a Path". Click that and the image path will be copied to the clipboard. Then you can past it on the imageUrl Attribute. 
(Example is given for a windows environment)